# Stable Id vs DiffCallback for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a custom class for data shown in my RecyclerView. Each object and thus each row has a unique id value for `id` field in the class.

Whenever I refresh data, the list gets cleared, repopulated and `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called. This causes for blinking effect.

During these refreshes, although id stays the same, some other fields are changing and some of these changing fields should be reflected in the item view.

Should I be using `setHasStableIds(true)` combined with `getItemId()` OR should I use DiffCallback where I can override `areItemsTheSame()` and `areContentsTheSame()`?

If I use former, I am not sure if it can detect changes in other fields and update the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, you should always prefer `DiffCallback`.  Stable IDs can only compare identity, but not contents.  This leads to exactly the blinking effect you describe on item content change, because `RecyclerView` is forced to assume that the content might have changed, and rebind it/execute the item changed animation.  `DiffCallback` has no such limitation, and will always do the right thing if the callback is correctly implemented.